# JavaScript regex replace inner quotes

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fix an inline javascript snippet with reg ex to be rewritten on an input field.

I have single quotes that wrap the inner double quotes and I want to convert the inner quotes to be single instead of double but I only want to convert them when the code appears as nested quotes.

Right now I'm doing the conversion for all instances of the quote which works but I might run into another problem.  I'll attach my code below.

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submit').bind('click', function(e) {
        var yourstring = $("textarea").val();
        yourstring = yourstring.replace(/'/g, "''");
        yourstring = yourstring.replace(/&quote;/g, "\"");
        yourstring = yourstring.replace(/&lquote;/g, "\"");
        yourstring = yourstring.replace(/&rquote;/g, "\"");
        yourstring = yourstring.replace(/&#34/g, "\"");
        yourstring = yourstring.replace(/&#8220;/g, "\"");
        yourstring = yourstring.replace(/&#8221;/g, "\"");
        yourstring = yourstring.replace(/&#34;/g, "\"");
        alert(yourstring)
    });
});​
```

HTML

```
<textarea style="width:400px;height:300px;">
function('');

<a onclick="$(".text").append('test');">Click Me</a>
<br/>
&lquote;test quotes&rquote;

&quot; generic quotes &quot;
</textarea>

<input type="submit" class="submit">
```

To be more specific I'm trying to get

```
<a onclick="$(".text").append('test');">Click Me</a>
```

To look like

```
<a onclick="$('.text').append('test');">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: I know this is a bit of a weird thing to try to do but I have issues with quotes in the database.

Comment: If your database code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you should fix that—rather than making it more difficult for users to submit quotes...

Comment: Database escaping should be done server-side, otherwise you're open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: No matter what you do or what's your clientele, no matter what your Javascript does, you're more than likely to be facing a black hat guy with the right tools sooner or later. Pretty much every black hat guy has these tools.

Comment: Agreed with @Jan and @Vicario. You should not seek answer for this problem as the design itself is not correct. Besides, it's not good practice to use jQuery inline with html. Instead of `onclick=`, you can use an event listener.

Comment: The onclick is just an example its not the actual code.

Comment: I was thinking of not let you submit if the quotes are within quotes so you get an alert.

Comment: I realize it could be vulnerable to SQL injection but only a small team has access and they don't know any better.

Answer (score 0):

The example provided does not seem to have anything to do with the database but a problem with the JavaScript code within the `onclick` attribute. That code actually doesn't have a valid syntax, but my guess is that you are trying to build some sort of editor for HTML code.

If you decide not to follow the recommendations in the comments above (which I agree with), to answer your question, here's an option for removing double quotes for text already surrounded by them:

```
var s = "<a onclick=\"$(\".text\").append('test');\">Click Me</a>";
var re = /"(.*)"/g;
var r = s.replace(re, function($0, $1) { return '"' + $1.replace(/"/g, "''") + '"'; });
console.log(r);
​
```